# Web grid search function using JS and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC. I try to implement **search box**.

I have a input box and a button:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="Search" id="Search" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="SearchButton" />
</div>
```

Then I use JS to receive user input and trigger a function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#SearchButton').click(function Search() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Search", "PCA")',
            data: { AutoCribItemID: $('#Search').val() },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                var data = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < result.Data.length; i++) {
                    data.push(result.Data[i]);
                }

                loadData(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Failed! Please try again.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Then in back end, there is a respond method:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Search")]
public JsonResult Search(string AutoCribItemID) {
    List<PCAModel> allRecords = new List<PCAModel>();
    allRecords = db.elements.Where(model => model.AutoCribItemID.Contains(AutoCribItemID)).ToList();
    return Json(new { Data = allRecords }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You can see this C# method returns a list to frontend. Then what I want to do is to show all data after searching to user.

Here is a method to show data after searching:

```
function loadData(result) {
    var table = $('<table id="indexTable"></table>');
    var thead = $('<thead></thead>');
    var trow = $('<tr class="header"></tr>');
    trow.append('<th>EffectiveDate</th>');
    trow.append('<th>ChangeAgree</th>');
    trow.append('<th>Client</th>');
    trow.append('<th>Installation</th>');
    trow.append('<th>AutoCribItemID</th>');
    trow.append('<th>RGBSupplier</th>');
    trow.append('<th>Price</th>');
    trow.append('<th>SubmitDate</th>');
    trow.append('<th>WINUserName</th>');
    trow.append('<th>Export</th>');
    thead.append(trow);
    table.append(thead);
    var tbody = $('<tbody></tbody>');
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        tbody.append(result[i]);
    }

    table.append(tbody);

    $('#indexTableBody').html(table);
    location.reload();
}
```

Note: 'result' parameter above is from C# function from backend.

The question is, web page shows all record in the table instead of showing searched data. I only need to show data after searching in web grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the structure of your AutoCribItemID's, my guess is that because you're using .Contains in your where clause it's returning *anything* that matches that search term.  So, for example, if you had integer IDs and someone searched for "1", it would return any ID that contains the number 1 including 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, etc.  You probably want to use an equality comparison instead, i.e. `model.AutoCribItemID == AutoCribItemID`

Comment: It seems that it is not the problem. I followed what you said but it's not working.

Comment: Was just a shot in the dark without knowing more about your application.

Comment: I found I got an JSON object from backend. This object includes all information I need. But I cannot convert this object to JS array.